# How can I translate this nested query into R dplyr?

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, subquery

I'm a newbie in R and I'm trying to translate the following nested query using dplyr:

```
SELECT * FROM DAT 
where concat(code, datcomp) IN 
(SELECT concat(code, max(datcomp)) from DAT group by code)
```

- DAT is a data frame containing several hundreds columns.
- code is a not-unique numeric field
- datcomp is a string like 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS'

What I'm trying to do is extracting from data frame the most recent timestamp for each code.
Eg: given

```
  code            datcomp
1   1005 2019-06-12T09:13:47
2   1005 2019-06-19T16:15:46
3   1005 2019-06-17T21:46:02
4   1005 2019-06-17T17:52:01
5   1005 2019-06-24T13:10:05
6   1015 2019-05-02T10:33:13
7   1030 2019-06-11T14:58:16
8   1030 2019-06-20T09:50:20
9   2008 2019-05-17T18:43:34
10  2008 2019-05-28T15:16:50
11  3030 2019-05-24T09:51:30
12  3032 2019-05-30T16:40:03
13  3032 2019-05-21T09:34:27
14  3062 2019-05-17T16:10:53
15  3062 2019-06-20T16:45:51
16  3069 2019-07-01T17:54:59
17  3069 2019-07-09T12:39:56
18  3069 2019-07-09T17:45:09
19  3069 2019-07-17T14:31:01
20  3069 2019-06-24T13:42:27
21  3104 2019-06-05T14:47:38
22  3104 2019-05-17T15:18:47
23  3111 2019-06-06T15:52:51
24  3111 2019-07-01T09:50:33
25  3127 2019-04-16T16:04:59
26  3127 2019-05-15T11:49:29
27  3249 2019-06-21T18:24:14
28  3296 2019-07-01T17:44:54
29  3311 2019-06-10T11:05:20
30  3311 2019-06-21T12:11:05
31  3311 2019-06-19T11:36:47
32  3332 2019-05-13T09:38:21
33  3440 2019-06-11T12:53:07
34  3440 2019-05-17T17:40:19
35  3493 2019-04-18T11:18:37
36  5034 2019-06-06T15:24:04
37  5034 2019-05-31T11:39:17
38  5216 2019-05-20T17:16:07
39  5216 2019-05-14T15:08:15
40  5385 2019-05-17T13:19:54
41  5387 2019-05-13T09:33:31
42  5387 2019-05-07T10:49:14
43  5387 2019-05-15T10:38:25
44  5696 2019-06-10T16:16:49
45  5696 2019-06-11T14:47:00
46  5696 2019-06-13T17:10:36
47  6085 2019-05-21T10:15:58
48  6085 2019-06-03T11:22:34
49  6085 2019-05-29T11:25:37
50  6085 2019-05-31T12:52:42
51  6175 2019-05-13T17:17:48
52  6175 2019-05-27T09:58:04
53  6175 2019-05-23T10:32:21
54  6230 2019-06-21T14:28:11
55  6230 2019-06-11T16:00:48
56  6270 2019-05-28T08:57:38
57  6270 2019-05-17T16:17:04
58 10631 2019-05-22T09:46:51
59 10631 2019-07-03T10:41:41
60 10631 2019-06-06T11:52:42
```

What I need is

```
    code         datcomp
1   1005 2019-06-24T13:10:05
2   1015 2019-05-02T10:33:13
3   1030 2019-06-20T09:50:20
4   2008 2019-05-28T15:16:50
5   3030 2019-05-24T09:51:30
6   3032 2019-05-30T16:40:03
7   3062 2019-06-20T16:45:51
8   3069 2019-07-17T14:31:01
9   3104 2019-06-05T14:47:38
10  3111 2019-07-01T09:50:33
11  3127 2019-05-15T11:49:29
12  3249 2019-06-21T18:24:14
13  3296 2019-07-01T17:44:54
14  3311 2019-06-21T12:11:05
15  3332 2019-05-13T09:38:21
16  3440 2019-06-11T12:53:07
17  3493 2019-04-18T11:18:37
18  5034 2019-06-06T15:24:04
19  5216 2019-05-20T17:16:07
20  5385 2019-05-17T13:19:54
21  5387 2019-05-15T10:38:25
22  5696 2019-06-13T17:10:36
23  6085 2019-06-03T11:22:34
24  6175 2019-05-27T09:58:04
25  6230 2019-06-21T14:28:11
26  6270 2019-05-28T08:57:38
27 10631 2019-07-03T10:41:41
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287648/dplyr-get-last-value-for-each-year might help you

Comment: thank you this was very helpful: I found 
  `dati %>%

  group_by(abi) %>%

  filter(datcomp==max(datcomp))`

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

a more generalized version - group, then sort so that you get whatever you want first, then slice (which would allow you to take the `n`th value from each group as sorted):

```
dati %>%
group_by(code) %>%
arrange(desc(datcomp)) %>%
slice(1) %>%
ungroup()
```